# Callback after setting height in jquery

Tags: jquery, callback

I set a height with jquery. After this height is set, another function shall be executed.
Is is important, that this function is first executed, when the first height was set.
This is my code

```
$('.equal-height2').height(max_height2, function() {  
            alert('###');
            pc_img_height   = $('.podcasts-meta-img').height();
            $('.podcasts-meta-img').width(pc_img_height); 
        })
```

The alert get so fired at the moment.

Comment: only one param for `.height()` you can use a callback but it should return the height see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7txa4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height()` doesn't have callback function, try `animate()`;

```
$('.equal-height2').animate({"height": max_height2}, function() {  
     alert('###');
     pc_img_height = $('.podcasts-meta-img').height();
     $('.podcasts-meta-img').width(pc_img_height); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

.height() will not create an animation - you don't need to use a callback here to do what you want.